# Issues with Cufon in Magento

Tags: jquery, magento, cufon

I'm trying to get Cufon working in Magento and it's not playing the game. jQuery is running in no-conflict due to Scriptaculous, and Cufon is initalising correctly (generating ready tags in the markup), though still no font transformations occur. The fonts in use are already applied on a mock up in a different directory on the same domain, so I'm very confused at to what could be the root of this.

Also - does anyone have any idea at all where the call to Cufon.now() would go for IE? Havn't found the true footer (inc. ) in Magento yet!

Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

A couple of things to try:

- Check that your MAGE_IS_DEVELOPER_MODE = false
  (otherwise JS paths seem to convert
  to local paths which my browsers
  don't like!)
- Check that the domain
  restrictions you placed on the file
  when using the Cufon generator are
  honoured.  If not, Cufon will die
  silently.  I've lost many hours
  because of this!

Good luck,
JD